# 1Kings 14:24 literal interpretation

Tags: hebrew, 1-kings

**וגם קדש היה בארץ**
and also the holy-consecrated living in the land

**עשו ככל התועבת הגוים**
they did all the abominations of the nations

**אשר הוריש יי מפני בני ישראל**
whom/which the LORD abandoned due to children of Israel

Just for the context, the prior verse:
**ויבנו גם המה להם במות ומצבות ואשרים על כל גבעה גבהה ותחת כל עץ רענן**
So built they also they for them high places and monuments and images on all high hills and under every green tree.

**Question:**
Which of the following is the verse saying?

1. The LORD had abandoned the abominations of the nations for the sake of the children of Israel.
2. The LORD had abandoned the nations for the sake of the children of Israel, due to the holy-consecrated of Israel having done all the abominations of the nations.
3. The LORD had earlier abandoned the nations for the sake of the children of Israel. Then the holy-consecrated of Israel did all the abominations of the nations.
4. Despite the LORD having abandoned the nations for the sake of the children of Israel,  the holy-consecrated of Israel still did all the abominations of the nations.

Answer (score 1):

The key word in this passage is [**קָדֵשׁ**](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=H6945&cscs=Num&sstr=0&t=NASB), which occurs in the singular and refers to the male (cult) prostitute and/or [synecdoche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche) for male (cult) prostitution, [and the term in the masculine singular occurs six times in the Hebrew Bible where the context is moral abomination](http://www.obohu.cz/bible/index.php?styl=BHS&styl_hled=ASV&k=Na&kap=1&ret=H6945&typ=1&omezeni=cela_bible&hled=adv&advsearch=Find). The triliteral root means to consecrate, and, depending on the context (as well as the vowel points evident in the Masoretic Text) the word designates what is "consecrated" to the sacred or to the profane. The context in [1 Ki 14:24](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Ki%2014%3A24&version=NASB) indicates something profane at hand (male cult prostitution), since the Hebrew phrases occurring before and after this Hebrew word refer to the Canaanite moral abominations that had once existed in the land.

Thus the subject of the second clause in [1 Ki 14:24](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Ki%2014%3A24&version=NASB) ("they") does not refer to the singular [**קָדֵשׁ**](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=H6945&cscs=Num&sstr=0&t=NASB) of the first clause, but to the people of Judah (plural in [1 Ki 14:22](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Ki%2014%3A22&version=NASB)), who (under the reign of Rehoboam) had committed the same moral abominations as their Canaanite predecessors, whom the Lord had driven out of the land earlier. These abominations included the institution of male prostitution in the land "consecrated" to Canaanite deities. The correct translation of the verse therefore would be

```
  1 Kings 14:24      
  "And there was male cult prostitution in the land. They (people of Judah) did according 
  to all the abominations of the nations which the Lord dispossessed before the sons of 
  Israel."
```

Finally, the [LXX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint) uses the word [**σύνδεσμος**](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=G4886&cscs=Num&sstr=0&t=NASB) to translate the Hebrew word [**קָדֵשׁ**](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=H6945&cscs=Num&sstr=0&t=NASB), since this verse in Greek is an otherwise exact parallel in the Masoretic Text. The Greek word carries the negative connotation of bondage (literally) or conspiracy (figuratively), [and occurs nine times in the LXX mostly in the figurative sense with the negative connotation](http://www.obohu.cz/bible/index.php?styl=LXXK&styl_hled=BES&k=Jl&kap=1&ret=G4886&typ=1&omezeni=cela_bible&hled=adv&advsearch=Find). Thus the people of Judah "did evil in the sight of the Lord" by committing the same moral abominations (to include male cult prostitution) that were committed by the Canaanites, who had once preexisted the people of Judah in the same land.

Comment: I do not accept the legitimacy of however many rabbis, priests or pastors it took to produce the Septuagint, Vulgate or the KJV. What parallel literature besides medieval opinions could you use to prove your point?

Comment: Yours could be reproduction of yet another dance around concepts to align translation to preconceived ideology. For example, Psalm 23:6, why couldn't people simply honestly translate it as *lengthened days* instead of *forever*? Why couldn't they simple-ly translate Psalm 8 as *nearly G-d* or *little less than G-d*, rather than presuming a prior theology that G-d would not want us to be as powerful as He is. As I am reading the Bible in Hebrew, deliberately blinding myself to other sources, I would never see it that way.

Comment: Also the question was not about the word קדש. It is about the ambiguity of the Hebrew grammar, trying to figure out which of the four or more possible cases the passage meant.

Comment: 1Kings 14:22 **ויעש יהודה הרע בעיני יי ויקנאו אתו מכל אשר עשו אבתם בחטאתם אשר חטאו** which translates as *And did he Judah the evil in eyes of the LORD and he lusted after all the  which their fathers did, in your sins which they sinned*. I have no idea where you got your translation because the Hebrew is so far from your translation. Therefore, my apologies, I have to vote you down for deploying that bad translation.

Comment: @BlessedGeek, Joseph used the wrong reference in his block quote. Typo. He meant 24 but typed 22.

Comment: @BlessedGeek, words change in meaning over time (in Mishnaic Hebrew, *'olam* means "world" not an indication of length of time). In the Hebrew Bible, there are places where it means "lengthened days" and [others](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/5769.htm) where it means "indefinite futurity" (and a few times even of "ancient past," e.g. Ecc 1:10). In the link, skip the Strongs section and go to Brown-Driver-Briggs. Many more details. Lastly, the LXX is ancient, not medieval. All scholars recognize that it can be a help (but not necessarily the final say) in interpreting a passage.

Comment: Frank, there is no olam in Psalm 23. I have searched the whole Bible, there is no לארך ימים elsewhere. Pls tell me where else there is "לארך ימים". "לארך ימים" is plain and simple, lengthened days, long time, but not forever. Stone's translation, the most orthodox of our translation does not translate as "forever".